# Firebase Cloud Functions npm install error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to get the Firebase Cloud Functions FCM [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) running. I've been following the steps as described in the README but I receive the following error when I try to run npm install in the functions folder.

```
npm WARN fcm-notifications-functions@ No repository field.
npm WARN fcm-notifications-functions@ No license field.
```

I then went on and deployed the code anyway using the command `firebase deploy`. It says that deploy was complete - the basic webpage from the sample is deployed and works but when I open functions in the firebase console there is no function :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those are warnings and are safe to ignore. Perhaps try refreshing the console?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I've tried refreshing it numerous times and there's no change.

Comment: What version of firebase-tools are you running? `firebase --version` if it's not up to date that will keep the deploy from succeeding.

Comment: I ran npm install -g firebase-tools to ensure that it was up to date. I then ran firebase --version as you suggested and it returned 3.1.0. I tried to deploy the code again but it sadly I don't see the function in the firebase console.